# VSCode needs to be restarted after modifying tsconfig and tslint files in nrwl nx projects to eliminate errors

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, nrwl-nx

I'm working on a project with Nrwl nx in VSCode and whenever I change a route to a library or the prefix for a library my code shows a bunch of false errors.  Everything still renders as expected but I need to reboot VSCode to make all the red lines and text go away.  Why is this happening?  Is there a way to do something in the terminal to reset/update whatever it is that corrects itself at reoot?

Answer (score 16):

I think a quick fix to this is to restart the TypeScript Server within VSCode using the Command Palette.

`CMD + SHIFT + P` then type `Restart TS Server`

you can also open the "Go to File" dialog using `CMD + P` and then type `>` to enter the Command Palette.

Comment: Great workaround!

Comment: Just for people who aren't familiar with using CMP + P, don't ignore the ">"  symbol in his answer like I did please.

Comment: @Boz my bad, you can also use `CMD + SHIFT + P` to enter the Command Palette directly

Answer (score 2):

This is a known (and buggy?) behavior in VSC. I use TS with Angular 12, and the following works for me:

1. Open the command palette using `Ctl + Shift + p` (or `Cmd + Shift + p` on Mac)
2. Type "`Restart Angular Language Server`"
3. On rare occasions that the above doesn't work, in step 2, you can write "`Developer: Reload Window`"

I hope Microsoft will fix this issue soon - until then, this is the best solution I know.