# Lint errors not being refreshed after fix

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, lint

In VS Code I get a lot of lint errors, but they do not refresh after fix. If you look in image I removed line 16 but it still appears.

Is this a bug in VS Code or how do these get removed?

[image]
Do I have to restart VS Code?

Comment: You don't appear to have actually fixed that.

Comment: If you look in image I removed line 16 but it still appears.

Comment: You're looking at terminal output. This was probably from a previous run of the linter back when that line existed. You probably want to install an eslint extension that puts these errors in your editor pane instead.

Comment: I am trying to that. But a pain in ... to disable TSLint.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can restart the lint server in VS Code.

Comment: well, that was what I assumed, the questions was: how, and maybe even: is this possible automatically.

Answer (score 28):

The accepted answer here is real bad, there's no actual explaination.

For ESLint: I pull this from this thread https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/477

To fix this you need to restart the lint server:

1. Use CTRL + SHIFT + P
2. Look for: ESLint: Restart ESLint Server

For TSLint: [VSCode needs to be restarted after modifying tsconfig and tslint files in nrwl nx projects to eliminate errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766957/vscode-needs-to-be-restarted-after-modifying-tsconfig-and-tslint-files-in-nrwl-n) (not sure why the answer got a -1 as this seems to be viable. If anyone knows please let me know!)

1. Use CTRL + SHIFT + P
2. Look for: Restart TS Server

Comment: This also works for searching and restarting black, flake8, and the python language server - so super handy, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Linter messages generated in the terminal by build tools and compilers are completely separate from the real time linting generated by extensions and shown in the VS code problems pane.

The latter will disappear automatically upon fix, but the former will only change once you rebuild or recompile.